# Cannot inject service in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, dependency-injection

I am new in Spring / Spring Boot and try to inject a service to a class. Although I have tried some approaches e.g. `@Autowired`, the service instance is always null and throws "NullPointerException" error. I am not sure if I need to register this class and service for DI, but as far as I know it is automatically registered when using `@Component` or similar annotation in the class. I think I miss some point, but have not found the problem. Could you pls have a look at the code and let me know where the problem or missing point is?

```
//@Component // I also tried with this, but employeeService is still null
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
public class EmployeeRequest extends PageableCriteriaRequest {

    @Autowired
    public EmployeeService employeeService;

    public List<SearchCriteria> getSearchCriteriaList() {        
        List<int> employees = employeeService.employeeList(); // NullPointerException 
        
        //code omitted for brevity
    }
}
```

Comment: you said it yourself, you're missing proper annotation...

Comment: @Marek Sorry, but I already used `@Component` and it was not visible due to backticks in the question. Now it is displayed. Any idea?

Comment: I think the order of the annotations is not important. Isn't it?

Comment: @Marek Would you test the code please?

Comment: just follow instructions from Akif Hadziabdic, you must properly annotate both EmployeeRequest and EmployeeService classes

Comment: @Marek I followed and tried all of them + some other combinations, but still the same *"NullPointerException"* problem. Any idea?

Comment: The fact that the class is named `EmployeeRequest` it probably means you are using this as an argument in a request handling method. Objects like that don't get injected by Spring.

Comment: @M.Deinum Yes, the problem is probably caused from that. many thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing `@Component` annotation.

```
@Component
public class EmployeeRequest extends PageableCriteriaRequest {

   @Autowired
   public EmployeeService employeeService;
  ...
}
```

Also, ensure that EmployeeServiceIml is also annotated with `@Component` or `@Service` annotation.

```
@Service
public class EmployeeServiceIml implements EmployeeService {
  ...
}
```

Also, ensure that you have `@SpringBootApplication` and all components in the same or sub-packages.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SampleApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SampleApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Akif, but I already used `@Component` and it was not visible due to backticks in the question. Now it is displayed. Any idea?

Comment: Do you have Component or Service on EmployeeService class or implementation class if EmployeeService is an interface? can you share the code?

Comment: EmployeeService is an interface and now I am trying to add `@Service` annotation to this interface. Should I add `@Service` annotation to the implementation of the service instead of interface?

Comment: Add `@Service` annotation to the implementation, and ensure that you have only one implementation of EmployeeService interface

Comment: What about `@Component` and `@Autowired` annotations? Where should I use them for fixing this problem?

Comment: `@Component` on class will add that class to spring context and whenever you use `@Autowired `spring context will inject added instance

Comment: Could you please update your answer by adding EmployeeRequest, EmployeeService and  EmployeeServiceImpl by adding proper annotations? Sorry, I have tried many combinations and I am really very confused as I am beginner for Spring :(

Comment: Many thanks for your helps. I have updated all the annotations as you mentioned in your last update. However, still null, I do not know where the problem is. I also build and start debug after each changes so that there is not any problem about that side.

Comment: Did you add `@SpringBootApplication` in the class where you have the main method?

Comment: Also, check are your components inside sub packages

Comment: Do I need to use any annotation e.g. `@RequiredArgsConstructor`?

Comment: Yes, `@SpringBootApplication` is added to the main method class.

Comment: What do you mean with *"check are your components inside sub packages"* ?

Comment: Everything is the same as you suggested, but the service instance is still null :(

Comment: can you share full code?

Comment: Sorry, but the problem seems to be related to @M.Denium's comment: *"The fact that the class is named EmployeeRequest it probably means you are using this as an argument in a request handling method. Objects like that don't get injected by Spring"*. So, thanks a lot for your help, marked as answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put `@Service` or `@Component` annotation on the top of EmployeeService class since that's the class' object you want to inject.

```
@Service
public class EmployeeService {
 // methods of EmployeeService
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I also tried it but I think I added unnecessary classes. So, could you please clarify me which annotation should I use in the following classes / services?

Comment: The following annotations or need another ones? `@Service`, `@Component` and `@Autowired`. ==> The following classes: `EmployeeRequest`, `EmployeeService` (this is interface) and  `EmployeeServiceImpl` (this is service class).